# socket "import" does not work "from" does! Whats the deal?

Tags: python, sockets, import

I am just starting on python and am trying to use it to do some basic network routines. 
I have 2 pieces of code that do the same thing, one working and the other not. When I use the `from socket import *` I do not trigger my exception code block. When I use the `import socket` way I do trigger my exception code block. I want to code it up the second way! Does anyone see any problems in my code or in my understanding of the language or modules usage? Why is the second way not working?

**Here is the working code:**

```
from socket import *

try:
    connSkt = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
except:
    print "[-] Exception occurred!"
```

**Here is the NON-working code:**

```
import socket

try:
    connSkt = socket.socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
except:
    print "[-] Exception occured!"
```

Comment: You need to use `socket.AF_INET` and `socket.SOCK_STREAM` in the second example. It probably would have been obvious to you if you weren't completely swallowing all exceptions. Don't do that!

Comment: That worked. Gave my self three kicks in my mental butt.

Comment: If you really want to catch all exceptions and turn them into output messages, at least output the exception itself, so you know what happened! For example, `except Exception as e: print "[-] Exception occurred: {!r}!".format(e)`. Then, instead of just knowing that something went wrong, you'll know that what went wrong was `NameError("name 'AF_INET' not defined")`, which will make things a lot easier to debug. (But in this case, it would be a lot simpler to just remove the `try`/`except` and let the full exception and traceback print out; get it working, then figure out your logging format…)

Comment: Never use single `except:`, use `except Exception:` instead.

Comment: abarnert: Thanks, had not get that into python yet. Will be using your code example in the future!

Comment: @cdonts: `except Exception:` isn't any better; the only difference is that you won't catch `KeyboardInterrupt` and similar exceptions. It's the `as e` part (and, of course, actually _using_ that `e`) that matters. With more specific cases, like `except ImportError:` or `except KeyError` when only one thing could possibly have gone wrong, so you don't need the exception for anything, leaving off the `as` can be acceptable, but for `Exception`, it's hard to imagine any case where that's useful.

Comment: @abarnert I already knew that and I still think using `except Exception:` is better. From PEP8: *A bare except: clause will catch SystemExit and KeyboardInterrupt exceptions, making it harder to interrupt a program with Control-C, and can disguise other problems. If you want to catch all exceptions that signal program errors, use except Exception: (bare except is equivalent to except BaseException:).*. It wasn't a reply to your comment, since I didn't see it when I wrote my message.

Comment: @cdonts: OK, I shouldn't have said "isn't any better", but "isn't enough better" or "isn't better in the right way". I did acknowledge the difference ("you won't catch `KeyboardInterrupt` and similar exceptions"). Anyway, sorry for carelessly overstating things, especially if you took it as insulting; it wasn't meant that way.

Comment: @abarnert There's no problem ;-)

Answer (score 3):

`AF_INET` and `SOCK_STREAM` are part of the `socket` module, which you need to specify for your second example to work:

```
import socket

try:
    connSkt = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except Exception:
    print "[-] Exception occurred!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Like dano said: You need to use socket.AF_INET and socket.SOCK_STREAM in the second example

```
import socket
```

creates a module object named socket where AF_INET, and SOCK_STREAM are included

```
from socket import *
```

imports all names from socket including AF_INET and SOCK_STREAM into the current namespace.

Comment: ... however, you should avoid wildcard imports if at all possible. They typically end up importing things you don't need or will never use, can import internals if __all__ isn't set, and make it much harder for linters and debuggers to find unused/missing symbols.